# JSON response not displaying in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, android-databinding, android-mvvm

I am working on one project where I am not able to get json response in my recyclerview but getting response in Viewmodel.

Following is my code. I tried to use debug pointer but I am not getting any information in logcat or debug tab.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG = "MainActivity"
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    private val retrofitService = RetrofitService.getInstance()
    val adapter = MainAdapter()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, MyViewModelFactory(MainRepository(retrofitService))).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        binding.recyclerview.adapter = adapter

        viewModel.movieList.observe(this, Observer {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: $it")
            adapter.setMovieList(it)
        })

        viewModel.errorMessage.observe(this, Observer {

        })
        viewModel.getAllMovies()
    }
}
```

Models

```
data class MobileProducts(
    val products: List<Product>
)

data class Product(
    val image_url: String,
    val name: String,
    val price: String,
    val rating: Int
)
```

Retrofit

```
interface RetrofitService {
         @GET("/nancymadan/assignment/db")
    fun getAllMovies() : Call<List<MobileProducts>>

    companion object {

        var retrofitService: RetrofitService? = null

        fun getInstance() : RetrofitService {

            if (retrofitService == null) {
                val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://my-json-server.typicode.com")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
                retrofitService = retrofit.create(RetrofitService::class.java)
            }
            return retrofitService!!
        }
    }
}
```

Viewmodel

```
class MainViewModel constructor(private val repository: MainRepository)  : ViewModel() {

    val movieList = MutableLiveData<List<MobileProducts>>()
    val errorMessage = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun getAllMovies() {

        val response = repository.getAllMovies()
        response.enqueue(object : Callback<List<MobileProducts>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<MobileProducts>>, response: Response<List<MobileProducts>>) {
                movieList.postValue(response.body())
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<MobileProducts>>, t: Throwable) {
                errorMessage.postValue(t.message)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

JSON RESPONSE

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "price": "34999",
      "image_url": "url",
      "rating": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "price": "999",
      "image_url": "url",
      "rating": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "test",
      "price": "34999",
      "image_url": "url",
      "rating": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "price": "999",
      "image_url": "url",
      "rating": 4
    }

,]}
```

What is missing can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

May be you forgot set LayoutManager for your recyclerview

place this line before set adapter

```
        binding.recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not set any LayoutManager for the RecyclerView, and RecyclerView will not work without LayoutManger. so you should
add this to your code :

```
 binding.recyclerview.setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(this))
```

and it will work if your MainAdapter class and the data have no problems.

Comment: I have already used in xml 

  app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"

Answer (score 0):

First thing you set layout manager for Recyclerview.

```
binding.recyclerview.setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(this))
```

If you set in XML then no need by programmatically.

After getting response of Viewmodel livedata when you observe list data.

You have set list in adapter but use notify.
Use this.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChange()
```

Or You can use **DiffUtill** for notifying data in adapter it's good way.

If all this not work then try this one time:::::::::

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG = "MainActivity"
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    private val retrofitService = RetrofitService.getInstance()
    val adapter = MainAdapter()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, MyViewModelFactory(MainRepository(retrofitService))).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
//call api first
        viewModel.getAllMovies()
   //then observe

        viewModel.movieList.observe(this, Observer {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: $it")
            adapter.setMovieList(it)
   //after set data in adapter then set recyclerview adapter
            binding.recyclerview.adapter = adapter
        })

        viewModel.errorMessage.observe(this, Observer {

        })
       
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already used   app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" in xml

Comment: I have added notifyDataSetChange as well, but it did not work. I am not at all getting anything in logcat, neither response nor error

Comment: try last code It will be work if you get data in livedata.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69333454/how-to-load-data-in-recyclerview

Please check this now