# How to load data in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

I am creating one Android app and trying to set the data in Recyclerview, I am using MVVM architecture pattern with kotlin, I can see data in logcat but when app loads I am not seeing any data in my recyclerview.  Following is my code.

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var productViewModel: ProductViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    val adapter = ProductAdapter()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        
        val productService = RetrofitHelper.getInstance().create(ProductService::class.java)

        val productRepository = ProductRepository(productService)
        productViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, ProductViewModelFactory(productRepository)).get(ProductViewModel::class.java)

        binding.recyclerview.adapter = adapter
        productViewModel.products.observe(this,{
            Log.d("TEST",it.toString())
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        })
    }
}
```

ProductAdapter

```
class ProductAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductViewHolder>() {
    var movies = mutableListOf<MobileList>()
    

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)

        val binding = AdapterLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
        return ProductViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val movie = movies[position]
        holder.binding.name.text = movie.products.get(position).name
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(movie.products.get(position).image_url).into(holder.binding.imageview)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return movies.size
    }

}

class ProductViewHolder(val binding: AdapterLayoutBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

}
```

Repository class

```
class ProductRepository (private val productService: ProductService) {

    private val productLiveData = MutableLiveData<MobileList>()
    val products:LiveData<MobileList>
    get() = productLiveData

    suspend fun getProducts(){
        val products = productService.getQuotes()
        if(products?.body()!=null)
        {
            productLiveData.postValue(products.body())
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class ProductViewModel (private val productRepository: ProductRepository ) :ViewModel() {
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            productRepository.getProducts()
        }
    }

    val products : LiveData<MobileList>
    get() = productRepository.products
}
```

Factory

```
class ProductViewModelFactory (private val productRepository: ProductRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return ProductViewModel (productRepository) as T
    }

}
```

Model

```
data class MobileList(
    val products: List<Product>
)

data class Product(
    val image_url: String,
    val name: String,
    val price: String,
    val rating: Int
)
```

JSON Response

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "price": "34999",
      "image_url": "url",
      "rating": 4
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "price": "999",
      "image_url": "url",
      "rating": 4
    },]}
```

Comment: I have already set layoutmanager in xml

  app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"

Comment: you are calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but where do you give your adapter data ? is doing `Log.d("TEST",it.toString())` and then   `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` sufficient ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody how to set data  then ?

Comment: you have a variable  `var movies = mutableListOf<MobileList>()` and then never assign any value to it ever again, so what's the point of `productViewModel.products.observe(this,{...` and then you even log the data, but the actual variable in the adapter never gets assigned anything then, right ? if the variable in the adapter stays empty, then logically it follows that your adapter will also stay empty

Comment: no, my comments are sufficient, and there are answers here you can look at too

Comment: @a_local_nobody I tried that way already but getting error Type mismatch.
Required:
List<MobileList>
Found:
MobileList!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all make sure you have `layoutManager` set on the `RecyclerView`.

The problem here is Your `ProductAdapter` never had the data . `notifyDataSetChanged` is not a magic stick to notify the adapter you modify/add/update the dataset and then You will call  `notifyDataSetChanged` . that's how it works .

In your case You have `movies` list your adapter but you never assigned anything to it its always empty .
There are several ways to it. Just to make it work You can have a method to add the data in your adapter and then notify it.

```
fun addData(data:List<MobileList>){
        movies.addAll(data)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Now when you get the data inside on change you call this method .

```
productViewModel.products.observe(this,{
       it?.let{ items ->
        adapter.addData(items)
       }
    })
```

This should work .

Update on type fix - Seems like your type is messed up . Why is your repo returns a object of `MobileList`? While you are using a list of `MobileList` in adapter . Your adapter should hold `var movies = mutableListOf<Products>()`.

```
productViewModel.products.observe(this,{
       it?.let{ item ->
        adapter.addData(item.products)
       }
    })
```

Comment: Type mismatch.
Required:
List<MobileList>
Found:
MobileList!

Comment: I have added a fix see if that works out for you . Otherwise you need to fix types in adapter and what you are returning from repo . basically you need to make sure what your RecyclerView represents products or MobileList .

Comment: yes it worked, I was using Mobilelist, it should be Product .

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69337652/how-to-get-the-total-count-in-cart-using-recyclerview-adapter