# How to get the total count in cart using Recyclerview Adapter

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Hi I am using Recyclerview with Adapter in my Android application. In my app I have product listing screen, where user can set the quantity in every list item. I am using two imageviews for increment and decrement the quantity. Now issue is , if I make 2 quantity for first product and 4 for second product, total count should be 6 for my cart screen, but I am not able to get total count. Following is my code for adapter, can anyone help me ?

```
class ProductAdapter(private val cellClickListener: CellClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductViewHolder>() {
    var productsList = mutableListOf<Product>()
     var cartList = mutableListOf<Product>()

   /* fun setMovieList(movies: List<MobileList>) {
        this.movies = movies.toMutableList()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }*/

    fun addData(data:List<Product>){
        productsList.addAll(data)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)

        val binding = AdapterLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
        return ProductViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val products = productsList[position]
        holder.binding.name.text = products.name
        holder.binding.price.text = products.price
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(products.image_url).into(holder.binding.imageview)
        var cartCount : Int=0


        holder.binding.cartPlus.setOnClickListener {
            cartCount++
            holder.binding.cartValue.text = cartCount.toString()
            cartList.add(products)
            //println(cartList)
        }

        holder.binding.cartMinus.setOnClickListener {
            cartCount--
            holder.binding.cartValue.text = cartCount.toString()
            cartList.remove(products)
           // println(cartList)
        }
        fun updatedData( updatedcartList:List<Product>){
            cartList.addAll(updatedcartList)

        }
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            cellClickListener.onCellClickListener(products,cartCount)
        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return productsList.size
    }



}

class ProductViewHolder(val binding: AdapterLayoutBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

}
interface CellClickListener {
    fun onCellClickListener(data: Product,count:Int)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `cartlist.size()` for total count.
and for using in activity define this in Adapter class:

```
class ProductAdapter(private val..
{
...
fun getCartSize():Int {
return cartlist.size()
}
...
}
```

and in the activity you can use :

```
adapter.getCartsize()
```

Comment: yes I have already used, thanks but I have one question, how can I pass that size to activity and set it in cart which I implmented in option menu

Comment: @NewBeeAndy I can't see the activity but you can define a method in the adapter like getCartSize() and 
use adapter.getcartsize() in the activity if you need more detail add your activity class in the question.
so I can update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

since you are just passing the list into the `recycleview` and want to use it in  fragment or activity. I would suggest using the list to get the total count for your items instead. You can use `sumOf` to your list.

you can use it like this before you pass to recyclver view.

```
val totalCount = list.sumOf { it.quantity }
```

or

```
 txtView.text = list.sumOf {it.quantity}.toString()
```